# How to reinstall Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I've been trying Dart x64 for a month (under Windows 8).

Unfortunately, I've removed the "\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\Pub\" folder. After that any Dart/Polymer project (including shipped samples like sunflower) stops showing anything in a browser without any error or exception.

I deleted the `\dart` folder, and some other dart folders that I'd found (`\Users\$user\Application Data\Pub\`, `\Users\$user\.dartium\`, `\Users\$user\DartEditor\`).

Then I'd reinstalled the Dart x64 (unpack zip-file), but problem still remains.

Then I'd removed Dart x64 and installed Dart ia32. In this case projects build with errors (can't find files from standard package), but work well in the Dartium browser.

I'd like to completely remove Dart and reinstall the new one. Can anyone help me start from scratch with Dart?

#### UPDATE:

I've deleted following Dart artifacts:

C:\Users\$user\dart\

C:\Users\$user\DartEditor\

"C:\Users\$user\Application Data.stagehand"

"C:\Users\$user\Application Data\Pub\"

C:\Users\$user.dartium\

C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local.dartServer\

But got the problem, described in the [How to make Dart Editor find referenced packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512148/how-to-make-dart-editor-find-referenced-packages) thread.
So question still actual.

Comment: Consider creating a bug report at http://dartbug.com.

Comment: The problem that the browser doesn't show anything is very probably caused by an **very** annoying behavior of the Dartium browser - it expires after 6 weeks and stops displaying anything without any hint about the expiration. As far as I remember this was fixed recently but you might not have the fixed version. Ensure you have installed a recent version.

Comment: For now I've a problem discussed in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512148/how-to-make-dart-editor-find-referenced-packages thread. The application works, but Dart Editor shows tons of errors.

Comment: As for bug report - unfortunately I do not know - how to reporoduce it.

Comment: They might respond with questions what to check for on your system I didn't think of.

Comment: I've submitted an issue on the dartbug.org: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23147