# How to make Dart Editor find referenced packages

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

In the Dart Editor (x64), I create a new project from the "Polymer Web Application" template.

Immediately after creation, Dart Editor runs pub get command, executes building workspace.

Then for every import directive, like

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
```

I got the following error: 
`Target of URI does not exist: 'package:polymer/polymer.dart'`

How can I make Dart Editor understand references for standard libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your pub-cache is corrupted which can usually be fixed by running `pub cache repair` from command line.

Comment: I've closed Dart Editor, then executed the "pub cache repair" command in the "C:\dart\dart-sdk\bin\ " folder, then opened Dart Editor again and created a new project with Polymer. But unfortunately got same errors for newly created project. :(

Comment: Can you manually check if the file can be found following the `packages/polymer/polymer.dart` path from your project directory? In which directory is your *.dart file where Dart complains about the invalid import?

Comment: Sure, the new project resides in the "\Users\$user\dart\test\" folder, and corrsponding package file exists by the following path: "\Users\$user\dart\test\packages\polymer\polymer.dart".

Comment: And where is your file containing the `import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';` line?

Comment: By the way, inspite of errors I can launch the project and looks like it works. This is very strange for me.

Comment: The file with wrong import is "C:\Users\$user\dart\test\lib\main_app.dart"

Comment: I could imagine that the project name `test` causes this problem.

Comment: "my_new_app" and "PolymerApp" names lead to the same result :( I'm stucked. In any case I appreciate your help, Günter! I've marked this answer as useful.

Comment: Did you just rename the folder or also the `name` field in `pubspec.yaml`? Did you run `pub get` again in the project with the new name?

Comment: I've created two new projects from scratch - with "my_new_app" and "PolymerApp" names.

Comment: What Dart version are you using?

Comment: Dart Editor version 1.9.1.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.9.1

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Recently I have heard that reinstalling Dart helped to fix some weird issues. Sorry, I just saw your previous question was already about reinstalling. I don't know about Dart on Windows.

Comment: I've already asked this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509118/how-to-reinstall-dart-editor. You edited it this morning :)

Comment: No problem, Günter! Thank you very much for trying to help me!

Comment: @TSV I wonder if it uses the registry on Windows. Maybe there are invalid dart entries there to delete? Worth a shot.

Comment: I'm using Atom with dartlang plugin now - it works like charm. Thank you guys!